# Child process stdout and stderr column sizes in Node.js

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, process, pipe

I want to monitor real time data coming from a child process in Node. I can do this with no problem with the following code snippet.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

(function(){

  "use strict";

  var processMonitor, processListen, processDeauth;

  var parseStreamDataIn = function(data) {

    var str = data.toString('utf8');
    console.log(str);

  };

  var init = function() {

    processMonitor = spawn('trafficmon' , ['-w'], {'shell': '/bin/bash'});

    processMonitor.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      //trafficmon uses stderr, nothing needed here...
    });
    processMonitor.stderr.on('data', parseStreamDataIn);
    processMonitor.on('close', function (code) {
      processMonitor = null;
    });

  };

  init();

})();
```

The problem is, the data being returned and logged in parseStreamDataIn() is being cut down to 80 characters (columns) per row, leaving half the data I want missing.

Example of trafficmon running by itself in a terminal window (That has been manually expanded to 120 characters wide)

```
EC:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  131        1        0    0   1  128 120614 HTTPS   SSL  cluster1.xxxxx.com
```

Example of my node script running the same command and logging the data into the same size terminal window.

```
EC:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  131        1        0    0   1  128 120614 HTTPS   SSL  clus
```

As you can see, the tail end of the string is being chopped off.

Is there any way I can tell my child process shell to return more than 80 columns per row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pty.js` allows you to specify things like number of columns.

```
var pty = require('pty.js');

var term = pty.spawn('bash', [], {
  name: 'xterm-color',
  cols: 80,
  rows: 30,
  cwd: process.env.HOME,
  env: process.env
});

term.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

term.write('ls\r');
term.resize(100, 40);
term.write('ls /\r');

console.log(term.process);
```

Comment: See `node-pty` on npm for the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pty